# How to install codec

Tags: codecs

How to install codec on live Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

If I try run `sudo apt-get update`, I get this message:

> comunicate "** (appstreamcli:6785): CRITICAL **: Error while moving old database out of the way.
>   "

Comment: Which codec do you want to install? There are many. What do you want to achieve with it ultimately?